# Update array from View

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array where I need to update the data using input field . I am using `ng-repeat` to show the input fields by the number of items in array.

```
$scope.textvalue =  ["center", "80mm", "retain", "22pt", "bold", "140%", "18pt", "bold", "140%", "36pt", "11pt", "bold", "normal", "absolute", "211mm", "20mm", "20mm", "20mm", "center", undefined, undefined, "end-on-even", "even-page", "9pt"]
```

So I have 24 fields according to the array items using `ng-repeat="x in textvalue track by $index"` .

How will I update specific items from the field and gets back the same array `$scope.textvalue` with updated value ? I am not much familiar with Angular JS .

**Example :-** *from second field ie; if I update "80mm" to "90mm" it will reflect back in the array.*

Comment: how you are going to update the array?

Comment: @SangramBadi on ng-click of course

Comment: `$scope.textvalue[index] = newValue` where index is the `$index` you use in `ng-repeat`..

Comment: @Adriani6 how can i use this by ng-model and on click function? I am getting `index is not defined`

Comment: @WhoAmI [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/9F68Y/1219/)

Comment: @Adriani6 yes, in my case the `var newValue = " ";` is from input field what user will input.

Comment: @WhoAmI Then change `newValue` to your input model..

Comment: @Adriani6 I did , but it's not getting update. Can you edit you fiddle with input field ?

Comment: @WhoAmI http://jsfiddle.net/9F68Y/1223/

Comment: @Adriani6 I am doing the same thing , but it's not getting updated. In fact in your fiddle every field is getting updated with the same value. I need to update field by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you want to update the values, but you can bind an inputs `ng-model` to `textvalue[$index]` :

```
<div ng-repeat="x in textvalue track by $index">
  <input ng-model="textvalue[$index]">
</div>
```

Will update the array when you change values in the input boxes. See how it works here -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/f5lBpPjXMbvjOMuyPRPV?p=preview**

---

Here is another way without `ng-model`. If you want the values to be updated with +1 when you click on a button :

```html
<div ng-repeat="x in textvalue track by $index">
  <button ng-click="update($index)">
    {{ x }}
  </button>  
</div>
```

```js
$scope.update = function(index) {
  var value = $scope.textvalue[index];
  var intValue = parseInt(value);
  var strValue = value.replace(/[^a-z\%]/g, '');
  if (!intValue || !strValue) return
  $scope.textvalue[index] = (intValue+1)+strValue
}
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/3Vc1q2TtzsTJPw7BixkM?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks exactly this I want . So on click will it get replaced by the old object? like on click in controller i am doing this  `$scope.save = function(index){
   $scope.textvalue[index];}`

Comment: @WhoAmI, Thank you for accepting the answer. See update, another way to update the array without `ng-model` and inputs, just a button.

Comment: @WhoAmI, updated the last example to support values with `%`, forgot that.

Comment: I got it thanks, I just want to know if  the object `$scope.textvalue` will get updated on click ?

Comment: @WhoAmI, yes - you can see it in the demo above http://plnkr.co/edit/3Vc1q2TtzsTJPw7BixkM?p=preview you can see the values in the top change when you click on a button,  this is "live" content of `$scope.textvalue` rendered out with `{{ textvalue | json }}`

Comment: Yes , I got this angular 2 way binding feature. Thanks.